# Ray Tracing - Geometric Sphere Intersection - Intersection function returns true for all rays despite no intersection

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, intersection, raytracing

I am writing a ray tracing project with C++ and OpenGL and am running into some obstacles with my sphere intersection function: I've checked multiple sources and the math looks right, but for some reason for every single ray, the intersection method is returning true. Here is the code to the sphere intersection function as well as some other code for clarification:

```
bool intersect(Vertex & origin, Vertex & rayDirection, float intersection)
{
    bool insideSphere = false;
    Vertex oc = position - origin;
    float tca = 0.0;
    float thcSquared = 0.0;

    if (oc.length() < radius)
        insideSphere = true;

    tca = oc.dot(rayDirection);

    if (tca < 0 && !insideSphere)
        return false;

    thcSquared = pow(radius, 2) - pow(oc.length(), 2) + pow(tca, 2);

    if (thcSquared < 0)
        return false;

    insideSphere ? intersection = tca + sqrt(thcSquared) : intersection = tca - sqrt(thcSquared);

    return true;
}
```

Here is some context from the ray tracing function that calls the intersection function. FYI my camera is at (0, 0, 0) and that is what is in my "origin" variable in the ray tracing function:

```
#define WINDOW_WIDTH 640
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 480

#define WINDOW_METERS_WIDTH 30
#define WINDOW_METERS_HEIGHT 20
#define FOCAL_LENGTH 25


rayDirection.z = FOCAL_LENGTH * -1;
for (int r = 0; r < WINDOW_HEIGHT; r++)
{
    rayDirection.y = (WINDOW_METERS_HEIGHT / 2 * -1) + (r * ((float)WINDOW_METERS_HEIGHT / (float)WINDOW_HEIGHT));
    for (int c = 0; c < WINDOW_WIDTH; c++)
    {
        intersection = false;
        t = 0.0;

        rayDirection.x = (WINDOW_METERS_WIDTH / 2 * -1) + (c * ((float)WINDOW_METERS_WIDTH / (float)WINDOW_WIDTH));

        rayDirection = rayDirection - origin;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SPHERES; i++)
        {
            if (spheres[i].intersect(CAM_POS, rayDirection, t))
            {
                intersection = true;
            }
        }
```

Thanks for taking a look and let me know if there is any other code that may help!

Comment: Well, `intersect()` has two `return true`s in it, which one does your debugger say keeps getting hit?

Comment: There should only be one "return true" statement; the other one just assigns "insideSphere" a true value.

Comment: Sorry, reading comprehension fail.

Comment: What's the point of assigning to intersection at the end of intersect?

Comment: The point is that if there is no intersection (the return false cases), then don't modify the referenced variable.

Comment: But modifying a local variable at the end of a function has no effect after the function returns, so why do it?

Comment: You're right, I've read too fast, that should be a reference.

Comment: Ah, good spot! Thank you I will fix that.

Comment: Can recommend enough to check that source https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-sphere-intersection

Answer (score 2):

It seems you got your math a bit mixed. The first part of the function, ie until the first `return false`, is ok and will return false if the ray start outside of the sphere and don't go toward it. However, I think you put the camera outside all your spheres in such a manner that all spheres are visible, that's why this part never return false.

`thcSquared` is really wrong and I don't know what it is supposed to represent.

Let's do the intersection mathematically. We have:

- `origin` : the start of the ray, let's call this `A`
- `rayDirection` : the direction of the infinite ray, let's call this `d`.
- `position` : the center of the sphere, called `P`
- `radius` : self-explanatory, called `r`

What you want is a point on both the sphere and the line, let's call it `M`:

- `M = A + t * d` because it is on the line
- `|M - P| = r` because it is on the sphere

The second equation can be changed to be `|A + t * d - P|² = r²`, which gives `(A - P)² + 2 * t * (A - P).dot(d) + t²d² = r²`. This is a simple quadratic equation. Once solved, you have 0, 1 or 2 solutions, select the closest to the ray origin (but which is positive).

**edit**: You are forced to use another approach that I will detail here:

1. Compute the distance between the center of the sphere and the line (calling it `l`). This is done by 'projecting' the center on the line. So:

   `tca = ( (P - A) dot d ) / |d|`, or with your variable names, `tca = (OC dot rd) / |rd|`. The projection is `H = A + tca * d`, and `l = |H - P|`.
2. If `l > R` then return false, there is no intersection.
3. Let's call `M` one intersection point. The triangle `MHP` have a right angle, so `MH² + HP² = MP²`, in other terms `thc² + l² = r²`, so we now have `thc`, the distance from `H` to the sphere.
4. With all that, `t = tca +- thc`, simply take the lowest non-negative of the two.

The paper you linked explain this, but without saying that it assumes the norm of the ray direction to be 1. I don't see a normalization in your code, that may be why your code fails (not verified).

*Side note*: the name `Vertex` for a 3d vector is really badly chosen, something like `Vector3` or `vec3` would be way better.

Comment: The algorithm we are using for this project is based on the algorithm in slide 13 onward in this presentation: http://www.vis.uky.edu/~ryang/teaching/cs535-2012spr/Lectures/13-RayTracing-II.pdf. You solution seems to make sense and I will try it just to see if it remedies my problem, but ultimately and unfortunately, I have to use the geometric algorithm.

Comment: Also highly agree with the comment on the name Vertex; the only reason it is being used is because it was recycled from an earlier project.

Comment: Ok, I will see your algorithm - might need some time, as I have to eat in the meantime ;)

Comment: Please, don't trouble yourself ha ha. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Done. This paper is not of premium quality though (between typos, incorrect definitions, overly and uselessly complicated problem definitions, etc...). Also, very important, it assumes that `rd` has a norm of 1.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. That's interesting. I'm going to tinker a bit more and see if I can get ahold of my professor to hear his thoughts (he has been MIA for awhile though). I'll post back when I discover/hear anything.

Comment: Well... despite this the paper still has nice figures. By the way, what is "MIA" ?

Comment: Apologies, ha ha, "Missing in Action"; I think he might be traveling because he has not responded to his emails lately. Hence my journey to here.

Comment: Can recommend enough to check that source https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-sphere-intersection